# How do I go about making this layout? Having so much trouble

Tags: android, xml, image, layout, text

I am trying to make a really easy xml layout and I can't seem to get it to look the way I want.

I attached a picture of what I want it to look like:

[image]

Basically, I have a static background image in my imagebutton at the top.  Below that I have a picture the user snapped in the Photo Box.  I assume I need an image view for that, but would it be possible for me to instead pass the pic to the background of an image button too so I can make the size easier to manage?

Based on what the user chooses in the options before this layout, an option photo is shown based on what they select.  The photo would display to the right of the centered image, if that option is selected.

Below that would be a centered text view, with another separate one below that.  Finally, I would have two buttons on top of each other at the very bottom.

Could someone show me a good way to get this layout and also tell me if it is possible to take a picture that is snapped and make it the background of an image button - or if that is a bad idea?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like for the most part, you just want a simple `LinearLayout`. For the part with the photo, you could use an embedded `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`.

As for the picture - you can easily set the background of any view or view group to any image (any view has an option to set the drawable for the background).

The only thing you should consider - for the purposes of making the UI more intuitive - is to slightly modify the image for the different states (focused, selected, etc), so that the user gets visual feedback when selecting the button via the trackpad, or when clicking on the button. A "drawable" has built-in support for multiple images for each state.

Comment: The photo will be static - just going to be a simple display of the image to a background...would using the background of a button be better than putting it to an image view, so that I can have the optional image to the right if the user so chooses?

Comment: right. or for the part of the photo you could as well use Gallery if you want that feature. Than a user can have multiple optional photos and slide through them.

Comment: Yeah, if you want scrollable images, the `Gallery` is a fantastic class. It pretty much does all the work for you.

Comment: really just want two images that would be sidebyside - how can I pass a bmp to the background of an image button if it needs to be set to drawable?

Comment: Check out the documentation on how to create a Drawable, and then look up `View.setBackgrounDrawable()`.